# Reading XML - how to?

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

I have an application that reads an xml file with sql statements and intends them in a sqlite database.
So far everything has worked well.

My problem starts when I change the android studio version to the last one. From there, it only reads half of each of the sql statements.

For example the following sentence:

```
<datos>INSERT INTO Receta (Nombre, Descripcion, Tipo, TipoMenu, Coeficiente, Comensales, Situacion, Modificacion, Fecha, Hora, Defecto) Values ('Tomate con mozarela', 'Lavamos los tomates y los cortamos a rodajas
Colocamos los tomates en un plato y sobre ellos las rodajas de mozarella
Ponemos albahaca, perejil o las hierbas que más os gusten y aceite de oliva. ¡Riquísima y fácil!', 'Primero', 'Normal', '7', '4', '0', 'N', '0', '0', 'S')</datos>
```

Just read:

```
INSERT INTO Receta (Nombre, Descripcion, Tipo, TipoMenu, Coeficiente, Comensales, Situacion, Modificacion, Fecha, Hora, Defecto) Values (
```

My code is:

```
private void crearRecetasDefecto() {
    ArrayList<String> aSentenciaReceta = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> aSentenciaIngredientes = new ArrayList<>();
    String mensaje = new String();
    XmlPullParser parser = this.getResources().getXml(recetas_defecto);
    String sentencia = new String();
    String nombre = new String();

    int state = 0;
    do {
        try {
            state = parser.next();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (state == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            nombre = parser.getName();
            switch (nombre) {
                case "datos":
                    sentencia = leerTexto(parser);
                    aSentenciaReceta.add(sentencia);
                    break;
                case "ingredientes":
                    sentencia = leerTexto(parser);
                    aSentenciaIngredientes.add(sentencia);
                    break;
            }
        }
    } while (state != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT);

    WebserviceUtilSqlite webservice = new WebserviceUtilSqlite(this);
    TaskCallbackdefecto(webservice.insertarRecetasDefecto(aSentenciaReceta, aSentenciaIngredientes));

}

private String leerTexto(XmlPullParser parser) {
    String texto = new String();
    int state = 0;
    try {
        state = parser.next();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (state == parser.TEXT){
        texto = parser.getText();
    }

    return texto;
}
```

The xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rootelem1>
    <receta>
        <datos>INSERT INTO Receta (Nombre, Descripcion, Tipo, TipoMenu, Coeficiente, Comensales, Situacion, Modificacion, Fecha, Hora, Defecto) Values ('Tomate con mozarela', 'Lavamos los tomates y los cortamos a rodajas
Colocamos los tomates en un plato y sobre ellos las rodajas de mozarella
Ponemos albahaca, perejil o las hierbas que más os gusten y aceite de oliva. ¡Riquísima y fácil!', 'Primero', 'Normal', '7', '4', '0', 'N', '0', '0', 'S')</datos>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Tomate con mozarela', 'Tomates ensalada', '2', 'kg', 'X')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Tomate con mozarela', 'Mozzarella fresca', '0.5', 'bola', 'X')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Tomate con mozarela', 'Perejil y albahaca', '1', 'pellizco', '')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Tomate con mozarela', 'Aceite de oliva virgen', '1', 'chorro', 'IngredientePrincipal')</ingredientes>
    </receta>
    <receta>
        <datos>INSERT INTO Receta (Nombre, Descripcion, Tipo, TipoMenu, Coeficiente, Comensales, Situacion, Modificacion, Fecha, Hora, Defecto) Values ('Huevos rellenos', 'Cocemos los huevos unos 16 minutos en agua hirviendo con un poco de sal.
Dejamos enfriar, pelamos, cortamos por la mitad a lo largo cada huevo, vaciamos las yemas y las reservamos.
Hacemos la mayonesa...ponemos en un vaso batidor el huevo, unas gotas de zumo de limón,s al y aceite,batimos con la batidora la cantidad deseada.
En un bol ponemos el atún escurrido, las yemas del huevo (reservamos 3 trozos) y mayonesa, removemos bien y rellenamos los huevos, decoramos con una aceituna en el medio y las yemas reservadas ralladas por encima.', 'Primero', 'Normal', '9', '4', '0', 'N', '0', '0', 'S')</datos>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Huevos rellenos', 'Huevos', '8', 'u.', 'X')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Huevos rellenos', 'Atún', '2', 'latas', 'X')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Huevos rellenos', 'Aceitunas negras', '4', 'u.', '')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Huevos rellenos', 'Mayonesa', '1', 'bote', '')</ingredientes>
    </receta>
    <receta>
        <datos>INSERT INTO Receta (Nombre, Descripcion, Tipo, TipoMenu, Coeficiente, Comensales, Situacion, Modificacion, Fecha, Hora, Defecto) Values ('Espaguetis boloñesa', 'En una cazuela ponemos 3 cucharadas de aceite y freímos los ajos cortados muy finos, cuando estén añadimos la carne picada y un poco de sal, lo damos unas vueltas y ponemos el vino, y la pimienta, lo dejamos 3 minutos y reservamos.
En una sartén freímos la cebolla picada y la zanahoria unos 12 minutos, y añadimos el tomate pelado y cortado en trozos pequeños, ponemos un poquito de sal y el azúcar, 15 minutos y lo añadimos a la cazuela con la carne, lo dejamos otros 10 minutos y probamos de sal.
En una cazuela grande con 6 L de agua y un poco de sal cocemos la pasta, a fuego lento medio ( la pasta debéis ponerla en el agua cuando comience a hervir ) cuando esté cocida la ponemos en un colador y podemos empezar a emplatar, colocamos la pasta en el plato, encima la salsa y por último unas ojas de albahaca encima.', 'Primero', 'Normal', '5', '4', '0', 'N', '0', '0', 'S')</datos>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Espaguetis boloñesa', 'Espaguetis', '600', 'gr.', 'X')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Espaguetis boloñesa', 'Cebolla', '1', 'u.', '')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Espaguetis boloñesa', 'Zanahorias', '4', 'u.', '')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Espaguetis boloñesa', 'Ajo', '2', 'dientes', '')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Espaguetis boloñesa', 'Carne picada', '500', 'gr', '')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Espaguetis boloñesa', 'Tomates maduros', '1200', 'gr', '')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Espaguetis boloñesa', 'Azúcar', '1', 'cucharadita', '')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Espaguetis boloñesa', 'Vino tinto', '0.5', 'vaso', '')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Espaguetis boloñesa', 'Caldo de carne', '0.5', 'l.', '')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Espaguetis boloñesa', 'Queso grana padano', '', '', '')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Espaguetis boloñesa', 'Albahaca fresca', '1', 'pizca', '')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Espaguetis boloñesa', 'Pimienta negra', '1', 'pizca', '')</ingredientes>
        <ingredientes>INSERT INTO Ingredientes (RecetaNombre, IngredienteNombre, IngredienteCantidad, IngredienteUnidad, IngredientePrincipal) Values ('Espaguetis boloñesa', 'Aceite de oliva', '', '', '')</ingredientes>
    </receta>
</rootelem1>
```

I have been testing and the problem is "'", as soon as it find a "'" the reading of the text is cut off.
I tried to change "'" by '"' and then read the entire statement but omit the '"' and when it does the insert in sqllite it cancels because it does not understand the sqlite syntax.
I have tried to put "'" instead of "'" but it stops at the first "&apos".

How can I put "'" and that the XmlPullParser understands it as a character?